# Quail dries out when cooked

Tags: roasting, poultry

What can be done with quail to ensure that it doesn't dry out when cooked?

(*note: the [other question about tender quail](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18037/26878), AFAICT, is specific to braising....my question is more about roasting, though advice about other cooking methods is also welcome!*)

> Inspired by [How to prevent the chicken breasts from drying out](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/46799/26878)

Comment: First post -- help with tagging and format appreciated!

Comment: How long are you cooking it for? Quail is small and lean, hot and fast is the way to go.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Haven't done it in a while, for fear of messing up again....probably too long. About how long do you think it should be done for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quail is small and lean, so fast and hot is the way to go. 200C/400F in the oven for about 20 minutes is about right, but trying to cook meat properly by time and temperature is a mug's game. Get an instant read digital thermometer from Amazon and get it right first time, every time.

You are probably looking at an internal temperature of 70-75C for quail, though if it's wild it *should* be slightly more forgiving than chicken in terms of food safety.